# C#, Sorting a LINQ result alphabetically then, sort it according to Search Key

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, search, sql-order-by

I'm retrieving data from a database using Entity Framework.

The result is filtered by a value entered in a Search TextBox.

```
var searchKey = this.TextBoxSearch.Text;

var products = this.databaseManager.Products.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchKey)).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Then the the result is sorted alphabetically.

```
products = products.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Now I want to sort the result in a way that; Results containing the **search key** at their beginning come before those containing the **search key** somewhere else in  the text.

Example:

When the user types **"iP"**
The filtered results should be as bellow :

iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, All in one iP Phone ......

Of course in normal cases **All in one iP phone** is the first item in the list. because the results are sorted alphabetically. But in my case. the user's  **search key** must be dominant.

Is this possible using C# Linq [.NET 4.5], Or in SQL Server ? if this can be done with an SQL query it's also good.

Comment: Find the index of the search key in the result set and sort according to the the index.

Comment: @Mokchhya , I want to the same , but how exactly do this? in which way problematically?

Comment: @rabar, Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var products = this.databaseManager.Products.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchKey)).Select(x => new {Name=x.Name,Index=x.Name.IndexOf(searchKey)}).OrderBy(a=>a.Index).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var ordered = products.OrderBy(p => p.IndexOf("iP"));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work in you case :

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => p.StartsWith("iP") ? 1 : 2).ThenBy(p => p);
```

Comment: if the search string was found in the middle or end, then resulted list will not be in ascending order as the OP wants...

Comment: Indeed, i only cared about "iP" being at the beginning.